# Can I position a button at the bottom of a card without position: absolute;? (vue-bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

So I'm trying to create a simple card with just a background image and a button, with the buttons link being stretched over the entire card. The button looks awful not at the bottom though, but if I use an absolute position, it removes the stretched link.

[image]

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>College Management Home</h2>

        <b-card
            class="sCardHome m-3"
            header="Courses"
            overlay
            img-src="https://picsum.photos/325/200/?image=26"
            img-alt="Card Image"
        >
            <b-button class="stretched-link homebtn" :to="{ name: 'viewCourses'}" variant="primary">View Courses</b-button>
        </b-card>

        <b-card
            class="sCardHome m-3"
            header="Lecturers"
            overlay
            img-src="https://picsum.photos/325/200/?image=27"
            img-alt="Card Image"
        >
            <b-button class="homebtn stretched-link" :to="{ name: 'viewLecturers'}" variant="primary">View Lecturers</b-button>
        </b-card>

        <b-card
            class="sCardHome m-3"
            header="Enrolments"
            overlay
            img-src="https://picsum.photos/325/200/?image=30"
            img-alt="Card Image"
        >
            <b-button class="homebtn stretched-link" :to="{ name: 'viewEnrolments'}" variant="primary">View Enrolments</b-button>
        </b-card>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'home',
    components: {}
}
</script>

<style>
.sCardHome {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 20rem;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
.homebtn {
    /* position: absolute; */
    bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
```

On a side note, is there a simple way I can have the cards margins stretch to fill the space, so the first card in a row is left aligned with the page & navbar title, and the last card in a row is right aligned with the logout button, so margins fill out the space in the middle so it all fits (in this instance, a margin left and right for the middle picture, can't be hard coded though as it needs to be responsive)? I tried the mx-auto class, on each cards and a div container, but neither worked at all.

Comment: Can you provide your css? What is the current content of the classes hometbn, stretched-link and sCardHome?

Comment: The css is in a style tag at the bottom, stetched-link is a bootsrap class though

Comment: Oh sorry I'm too dumb to scroll xD

Comment: Haha, no worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by utilizing flexbox.

Bootstrap provides some utility classes. This includes [display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/) like `d-flex` which applies `display: flex` to an element.
We'll apply this card to out card body via the `body-class` prop on `<b-card>`.

Then to get the button position, we can use a auto margin. Luckily for us Bootstrap provides [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/) for this. So here we can apply `mt-auto` (`margin-top: auto`) to push the button to the bottom. If we want to center the button horizontally we apply the `mx-auto` (`margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`) class as well.

There are other ways to position elements with flex, if you want to see some alternatives you can check out the [flex utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/) page on the bootstrap docs.

##### Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <b-card-group>
    <b-card v-for="i in 2" class="m-3" header="Courses" overlay img-src="https://picsum.photos/325/200/?image=26" img-alt="Card Image" header-class="text-center" body-class="d-flex">
      <b-button class="stretched-link mt-auto mx-auto" variant="primary">
        View Courses
      </b-button>
    </b-card>
  </b-card-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved! It works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox to make this work. I am not completely sure if that works with the stretched-link. But maybe you could try. Just add "display: flex;" to your sCardHome-Class. Give the homebtn-class a static height and set margin in general to auto and margin-bottom to a static value. This way the Button will always be at the bottom of the card and centered.

```
.sCardHome {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 20rem;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
}
.homebtn {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried it out, and a few variations of your suggestion, but it's not working unfortunately. There's nothing pushing the button down and it stays at the top. Is setting a static height for the card and button necessary?

Comment: Ah sorry the card height was for testing. I removed it. I tested the button-height. It is really not necessary.